# change button backgorund color within a toolbar

Tags: css, button, extjs4, background-color, toolbar

I want to change the background color of a button in a toolbar.
I need this button to show a summary-value.

I tried with

```
cls: 'button-matching-auto',
```

and in css-file

```
.x-btn-button .button-matching-auto {
    background-color: #10E0E0;
}
```

No effect.

Then i tried with

```
style: {color:'red'},
```

It's the same: no effect

In Developer Tools of chrome i can see, that the colors were applied,
but not visible.

What's wrong?

Comment: can you share your html? and a fiddle if is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"It's because the button has a CSS class named 'x-button' with a background-color set to '#CCC' by default..."**  http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?208417-Change-image-button

```
{
xtype: 'button',
baseCls: 'null',
cls: 'buttonRed
}
```

... if you only want the default look and feel of a button not the gray one ...

**I've done this to change the look and feel to get the default one:**

```
dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        layout: {
            pack: 'center'
        },
        defaultButtonUI: 'default', // get default look and feel
        dock: 'bottom',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            width: 200,           
            text: 'Download to Excel',

        },{
            xtype: 'button',
            width: 200,           
            text: 'Another action',

        }]
```